# Cisco CME to CME - phone rings but silence on pickup

Tags: cisco, router, voip

I have two Cisco 2901 routers with CME, DSP module and built-in poe switches. They are both linked together via Ethernet.

I have 2 phones connected to each router. Making calls between 2 phones on same router is working fine.
I have set up dial peers and can place a call from a phone on router1 to a phone on router2. The phone rings fine but when I pick it up there is silence, I cannot hear audio between calls. When I hang up one phone the other one cuts off, so call setup seems to be working great.

I will post config tomorrow but wondered if there is a straightforward reason for this. Is it a codec issue? (I am using g729r8 in my dial peers currently.)

Many thanks

Comment: Could you post somewhere the voip sections of the sanitized configurations?

Comment: Also - what kind of phones?

Comment: Config for Router2 is at http://pastebin.com/xNJLfUd6. Config for both Routers is the same, other than R1 IP=10.10.1.0. Phones are configured 10.10.1.2, 10.10.1.4 and 10.10.2.2, 10.10.2.4 for R1 & R2 respectively. Phones are 6911 model, protocol between routers is H.323 Could you also advise if there is anything related to this in my config that doesn't need to be there. Many thanks for your help –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. I hadn't added...

```
ip routing
```

to my config, was shown previously as

```
no ip routing
```